# how to redirect from a function to a url using name attribute + "?next=next_path" in django redirect?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

`view.py`

```
def register(request):
    next_cart_page = request.GET.get('next', '')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        status =  logic.register_logic(request)
        if next_cart_page == 'cart':
            return redirect("/u/o/?next="+ next_cart_page) <- instead of "/u/o/" how can i use "verify_otp_user"
        else:
            return redirect("verify_otp_user")
```

`main.js`

```
$('.checkout_login_required').click(function(){
    $('#register_user_link').attr('href', function(i, val){
        return val + '?next=cart'
    })
 });
```

using javascript i'm passing a value to the **next** key to an anchor tag.
then on `views.py` i'm checking for that value in an if statement and based on that i'm redirecting to the next page with or without the **next** value

in else statement i'm using path **name** attribute to redirect to a url
how can i do the same in if statement as well while concatinating path name attribute(like  `verify_otp_user`) with `"?next=" + next_cart_page`
something like  `redirect("verify_otp_user" + "?next=" + next_cart_page)`, but this is not working . Any alternate solution if available ?

**Note: `verify_otp_user` does not have any parameter in its url its simply `/u/o/`**

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```py
return redirect('verify_otp_user', next=next_cart_page)
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) (second example).

Comment: this will work only if i have a ```/u/o/<id>/``` but i don;t have a url i'm passing data using ```?next=abc ``` as a value

Comment: Then you should better add your `urls.py`.